How to get Kover report which contains coverage of one sub-project from tests executed in another sub-project?
Consider the following settings.gradle.kts
include("domain")
include("app")
include("special-e2e-test-suite")

As you can see, I have some special test suite in a dedicated Gradle sub-project (special-e2e-test-suite).
If I execute special-e2e-test-suite:koverHtmlReport, then I get an empty html report, because special-e2e-test-suite contains only src/test, but does not contain src/main. That makes sense, because Kover in this module is not aware about what are the other source sets, which should be considered for coverage reporting. What I would want to see is: how much code from domain and app is covered by tests from special-e2e-test-suite only?
There is a merging feature, which I can use on a root-level project as follows:
dependencies {
 kover(project(":domain"))
 kover(project(":app"))
 kover(project(":special-e2e-test-suite"))
}

but the problem is that my final root report in this case will contain coverage results from ALL test suites (while I actually would not want to get coverage from domain/src/test and app/src/test)
